# Glade Ubuntu - Transparent Button on a background image

Tags: quickly, glade

I'm trying to make an Ubuntu application. I need to place transparent buttons on specific locations on a background image in Glade, such that the image changes on button click.

I've not been able to achieve this so far. My button simply doesn't land on the image. Further, I also haven't been able to make the button completely transparent (i.e. It's visible when pressed).

Comment: May be I missed it, you mean Window Background not Desktop Background, right?

Comment: Yes I meant window background. :)

Answer (score 1):

1. For fixed buttons position, it's better to use `GtkFixed` or `GtkLayout` (with scroll)
2. For buttons transparency,  for me it's works as it should. If not try:

   - `Border Relief`: `None` for flat button
   - Uncheck `Focus on Click` for avoid any focus highlight

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.16.1 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.10"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkLayout" id="layout1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button1">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
            <property name="width_request">59</property>
            <property name="height_request">30</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <property name="opacity">0</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">87</property>
            <property name="y">64</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

---

For 1st time, I thought you mean Desktop Background. So, I just leave it may be helpful for others.

I'm not sure which version of PyGTK is used by Quickly in (Ubuntu 13.04). Better to use 0.1 opacity to test. Glade does not provide the option to set `keep_below` property.

### PyGTK 3

Add:

```
    <property name="opacity">0.0</property>
    <property name="decorated">False</property>
```

To

`builder_example.glade`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <!-- interface-requires gtk+ 3.0 -->
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <!-- <property name="keep_below">True</property> -->
    <property name="opacity">0.0</property>
    <property name="decorated">False</property>
    <!-- <property name="position">gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER_ALWAYS</property> -->
    <signal name="delete-event" handler="onDeleteWindow" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkButton" id="button1">
        <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
        <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <property name="receives_default">True</property>
        <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
        <signal name="pressed" handler="onButtonPressed" swapped="no"/>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

I have commented these, as they raised errors (I'm not sure if there is other way in Glade)

```
    <!-- <property name="keep_below">True</property> -->
    <!-- <property name="position">gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER_ALWAYS</property> -->
```

So, I add them to .py file to be applied dynamically:

```
window.set_keep_below(True)
window.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER_ALWAYS)
```

`builder_example.py`

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class Handler:
    def onDeleteWindow(self, *args):
        Gtk.main_quit(*args)

    def onButtonPressed(self, button):
        print("Hello World!")

builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("builder_example.glade")
builder.connect_signals(Handler())

window = builder.get_object("window1")
window.set_keep_below(True)
window.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER_ALWAYS)
window.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

### PyGTK 2

Add:

```
        self.window.set_keep_below(True)
        self.window.set_opacity(0.0)
        self.window.set_decorated(False)
        self.window.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER_ALWAYS)
```

to `helloworld.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# example helloworld.py

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

class HelloWorld:

    # This is a callback function. The data arguments are ignored
    # in this example. More on callbacks below.
    def hello(self, widget, data=None):
        print "Hello World"

    def delete_event(self, widget, event, data=None):
        # If you return FALSE in the "delete_event" signal handler,
        # GTK will emit the "destroy" signal. Returning TRUE means
        # you don't want the window to be destroyed.
        # This is useful for popping up 'are you sure you want to quit?'
        # type dialogs.
        print "delete event occurred"

        # Change FALSE to TRUE and the main window will not be destroyed
        # with a "delete_event".
        return False

    def destroy(self, widget, data=None):
        print "destroy signal occurred"
        gtk.main_quit()

    def __init__(self):
        # create a new window
        self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)

        # Add these
        self.window.set_keep_below(True)
        self.window.set_opacity(0.0)
        self.window.set_decorated(False)
        self.window.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER_ALWAYS)

        # When the window is given the "delete_event" signal (this is given
        # by the window manager, usually by the "close" option, or on the
        # titlebar), we ask it to call the delete_event () function
        # as defined above. The data passed to the callback
        # function is NULL and is ignored in the callback function.
        self.window.connect("delete_event", self.delete_event)

        # Here we connect the "destroy" event to a signal handler.
        # This event occurs when we call gtk_widget_destroy() on the window,
        # or if we return FALSE in the "delete_event" callback.
        self.window.connect("destroy", self.destroy)

        # Sets the border width of the window.
        self.window.set_border_width(10)

        # Creates a new button with the label "Hello World".
        self.button = gtk.Button("Hello World")

        # When the button receives the "clicked" signal, it will call the
        # function hello() passing it None as its argument.  The hello()
        # function is defined above.
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.hello, None)

        # This will cause the window to be destroyed by calling
        # gtk_widget_destroy(window) when "clicked".  Again, the destroy
        # signal could come from here, or the window manager.
        self.button.connect_object("clicked", gtk.Widget.destroy, self.window)

        # This packs the button into the window (a GTK container).
        self.window.add(self.button)

        # The final step is to display this newly created widget.
        self.button.show()

        # and the window
        self.window.show()

    def main(self):
        # All PyGTK applications must have a gtk.main(). Control ends here
        # and waits for an event to occur (like a key press or mouse event).
        gtk.main()

# If the program is run directly or passed as an argument to the python
# interpreter then create a HelloWorld instance and show it
if __name__ == "__main__":
    hello = HelloWorld()
    hello.main()
```

### References:

- [Python GTK+ 3 Tutorial: 20. Glade and Gtk.Builder](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/builder.html)
- [PyGTK 2.0 Tutorial: Chapter 2. Getting Started](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/ch-GettingStarted.html#sec-HelloWorld)
- [PyGTK 2.0 Reference Manual: gtk.Window - The gtk Class Reference](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtkwindow.html)

Comment: Thanks a ton! Yet to try your solution, but I'm very grateful that you took the time to compose this. Thanks for the ref docs as well!
Will try and update.